# Does it follow that there are at most $n+\pi(n-1)$ distinct primes that divide $\dfrac{(x+n)!}{x!}$

Tags: prime-numbers, solution-verification, prime-factorization

I've been thinking about the total number of distinct primes and it occurred to me that for any integers $x > 0, n > 0$, there are at most $n+\pi(n-1)$ distinct primes that divide $\dfrac{(x+n)!}{x!}$

Here is my thinking:

(1)  To simplify the discussion let $f(x,n) = \dfrac{(x+n)!}{x!}$

(2)  There are exactly $\pi(n)$ primes $p$ such that $p \le n$

> Where $\pi(n)$ is the [prime counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function).

(3)  For primes that are $n$ or greater, it follows that only  one number in $x+1, x+2, \dots, x+n$ can be divisible by such a prime.

This is impossible because for any integer $0 < i < j < n$, $x + j - (x + i) = j-i < n$

(4)  So, the result is that maximum number of distinct primes is $n+\pi(n-1)$

Is my reasoning correct?  Is this well known?  Is there an improvement to this result that I am missing?

Comment: Already for $n=1$ , we get $x+1$ which can have arbitary many prime divisors, since $x$ has not been restricted.

Comment: You are right.  $\pi(n-1)$ is not correct.  Would it still work with $\pi(\sqrt{x+n}) + n$.  In the case of $x+1$, there could only be a maximum of $\pi(\sqrt(x+1) +1$.  Am I wrong with this update?

Comment: As $n!|\frac{(x+n)!}{x!}$ it can be concluded that the number of dividing primes $p≤\pi(x+n)-\pi(x)+\pi(n) \leq n+\pi(n-1).$.

Comment: @AlapanDas I like your equation.  It is not obvious to me why it is true.

Comment: There cannot be an upper bound that is independent from $x$

Comment: The upper bound I wrote is directly applicable when $n>x$. For $x>n$ it need more.